# Unable to integrate prime faces components into xhtml using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces

1.I am unable to integrate primeface components in palette tool in eclipse Luna.Can you suggest me fine solution for that?
2.when I was trying to drag and drop the primefaces components into xhtml webpage editor or jsp web page editor,its not happening.If at all the primeface components are added to JSP page webpage editor.The component that is dropped in webpage editor its not visible but its effecting the code .

this is the issue

Comment: for 2 I give the answer, and if 1 fails, how can you drag/drop them?

Comment: no  yar,that is what I am asking just give me solution how can I add primefaces 6.0 components to pallete

Answer (score 0):

The 'visual' jsf designer in eclipse (or any ide) is of limited use. It can only show basic jsf components and some older RichFaces ones if you install the jboss extensions. Since it is fairly easy to run an embedded container, displaying it in a real browser is the better solution. Automagically reloading a page in the browser when saving in the IDE is possible (search the internet for this)

Comment: Its not the issue,

Comment: Actually I have two issues can you please go through the issues I posted once,please

Comment: If this is not your issue, it is totally unclear what it is.